# What about \cyrdash in EU1 and EU2 encodings?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, input-encodings, font-encodings

`cyrdash` is defined in `T2A`, `T2B`, `T2C` and some other legacy encodings but seems to escape from EU1 (xetex) and EU2 (luatex) encodings. `cyrdash` should, by idea, print something intermediate between `\textemdash` and  `\textendash` (`\cyrdash` is 20% shorter than `emdash`). It is used in Russian, Ukrainian, Bulgarian and Mogolian languages instead of `emdash`, so these languages are by fact discriminated.

If I am right and `\cyrdash` is indeed lost, could the latex development team please extend `EU1` and `EU2` encodings to provide a text command for `\cyrdash`? It might be called `\textcyrdash`.

What is the codepoint of `cyrdash` in Unicode tables?

**UPDATE**: Here is Minimal Working Example. Results depend on the engine used to compile the example. I tried xelatex and pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\else
    \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\Large

Russian: \\
!---!=\verb!---!\\
!\foreignlanguage{english}{---}!=\verb!\foreignlanguage{english}{---}!\\
!\cyrdash!=\verb!\cyrdash!\\
!\textemdash!=\verb!\textemdash!\\
!\textendash!=\verb!\textendash!\\

%!---!\par
\selectlanguage{english}
%!---!

English: \\
!---!=\verb!---!\\
!\cyrdash!=\verb!\cyrdash!\\
!\textemdash!=\verb!\textemdash!\\
!\textendash!=\verb!\textendash!\\

\end{document}
```

`Babel` with option `russian` redefines ligature `---` through `\cyrdash`. Pdflatex takes `\cyrdash` and `\textemdash` from a same codepoint of LH font if Russian language is selected; then their sizes are equal; if Englsih is current language than `\cyrdash` is undefined (rises an error), and `\textemdash` is taken from CM fonts and is longer as compared to itself in case if Russian is selected.

In case of `xelatex`, `\cyrdash` macro is not defined in current encoding so `babel` fakes it as `\hbox to 0.8em{--\hss--}` which turns out to be approximately 80% of `\textemdash`.

Ulrike Fischer directed me to a valuable list of all available dashes in Unicode. I did not find a reasonable candidate for `\cyrdash` there although from my own experience of publishing books I know that editors of Russian publishing houses sometimes are very rigorous regarding the size of dashes. I would also agree that Microsoft Word automatically produces correct dashes between russian words but I am not sure (and cannot check right now) if it produces longer dashes between English words.

So I don't see now a good uniform solution for `\cyrdash` in case when it should be taken from the same font as `\textemdash`. Perhaps, except that soultion which is currently used in babel-russian. Can some one propose a better way?

**UPDATE 2**: My original vision of the problem was wrong. With the aid of respected TeX'perts it became clear that legacy LaTeX engines take `\cyrdash` and `\textemdash` from the same codepoint `22` but possibly from different fonts. As a result, ligature `---` might change its length after `\selectlanguage`. So, now I would reformulate my question as follows:

**Is is good or bad practise to mix two versions of ligature `---` (which differ by their width) in the same multilanguage document?**

Comment: The Unicode 'encodings' have been merged into a new `TU` name, but these are not encodings in the traditional sense. They reflect that fact that for a Unicode font there is 'nothing to do here': each font slot is defined by the Unicode Consortium. If the latter don't provide a suitable dash then it can't appear in `TU`, though one can of course define `\cyrdash` as a macro.

Comment: BTW, this looks like a feature request to me, which would be off-topic for the site (only addressable by the appropriate developers).

Comment: You can find a list of unicode points for dashes here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm. If your dash is there (and your font has a suitable glyph) you can easily define a command for it. It is not a discrimination if no command exists yet: latex can't predefine commands for the whole unicode range. (There is a `\textthreequartersemdash` which points to U+2012).

Comment: or perhaps ﹘ (U+FE58 small em dash)?

Comment: Can you link to a cyrillic website using this dash so we can see which codepoint is being used?

Comment: The listings for traditional cyrillic encodings used by web browsers such as https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/index-koi8-u.txt do not list a separate dash for Cyrillic?

Comment: With a minimal demo document `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\cyrdash
\par
\textemdash
\end{document}` both are `\char"16` and thus the same length.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I don't know such a website. `\cyrdash` as 0.8 of `emdash` is faked in babel-russian, babel-ukrainian and babel-bulgarian packages, gloss-russian.ldf of polyglossya, e.t.c. and as a codepoint in T2* encodings. Microsoft Word produces a dash of resonable size automatically when one types two - between 2 russian words.

Comment: T2enc defines `\DeclareTextSymbol{\cyrdash}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{22}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textemdash}{\LastDeclaredEncoding}{22}` that is `\cyrdash` and `\texemdash` are defined but have identical definition.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139748/cyrillic-em-dash-is-rendered-inconsistently

Comment: Dear @JosephWright, I am bit suprised. I usually work with xelatex and my experience came mainly from there. I added a MWE to my question.

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle, You are right, and I updated my question.

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle, I reformulated my question as follows: Is is good or bad practise to mix two version of ligature `---` in same multilanguage document? What is your opinion?

Comment: Dear @UlrikeFischer, I reformulated my question as follows: Is is good or bad practise to mix two version of ligature `---` in same multilanguage document? What is your opinion?

Comment: Dear @JosephWright, I reformulated my question as follows: Is is good or bad practise to mix two version of ligature `---` in same multilanguage document? What is your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no Unicode code point for `\cyrdash`, but you can typeset it in xetex and luatex as `\cyrdash` or as `"---` if you include `\usepackage[babelshorthands=true]{polyglossia}` in your preamble.

Comment: Poluglossia in fact fakes `\cyrdash` using `\def`. As discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139748/cyrillic-em-dash-is-rendered-inconsistently it would be more correct to use `\DeclareTextCommandDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

Running it with `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
[...]
```

[image]